# Is it possible to both read and save Visual Studio 2010 Solutions with a Linux IDE?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I'm currently taking a beginning class on C++. The professor is all gung-ho about IDEs; I am not. Fine and well. The problem is that he wants all assignments turned in using the Solutions that MS Visual Studio 2010 creates. I only have Ubuntu at home.

Now, there are two things I can do already: First, I can just do my homework at my school's computer lab. Or, second, since the assignments are simple, I could just make my .cpp and header files on a text editor at home, bring them to the computer lab, and make the Solutions there.

What I am wondering: is there a way I can not only read the solution folders (which there seem to be some complicated methods for) but also store them in the format that Visual Studio likes? If there is, would it save me the 20 - 30 minutes per class period that going to the computer lab would cost me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Mono Develop](http://monodevelop.com/.)

Also keep in mind that as a student you'll likely qualify for Microsoft's [DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/) program via which you can use Visual Studio 2010 at no cost. Windows 7 runs great in VirtualBox under Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry it took me so long to respond. Mono Develop does not seem to be able to interpret the VS 2010 solution files I create at school. And am I right in understanding that Virtual Box requires that I still have a copy of Windows 7 to run on it? If so, I don't have one.